# Finding loss mask of variable length in keras tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

Trying to build loss function which captures the below functionality, which mask the output values once 'end of sequence' is encountered.

Given a tensor of shape [BatchSize,MaxSequenceLenght,OutputNodes]

Consider the below example

```
    batch size = 3
    Max Sequence Length=4
    OutputNodes = 3
    predicted = [[[0.1,0.3,0.2],[0.4,0.6,0.8],[0.5,0.2,0.3],[0.0,0.0,0.99]],
            [[0.1,0.3,0.2],[0.4,0.9,0.8],[0.5,0.2,0.9],[0.4,0.6,0.8]],
            [[0.1,0.3,0.2],[0.4,0.9,0.8],[0.5,0.2,0.1],[0.4,0.6,0.1]]]
```

I am dedicating the last output node to symbolise the 'end of sequence(EOS)' here node=2 . Nodes are labelled as (0, 1 and 2)

Based on the predicted value, I have to return a mask which tries to find the first occurrence of EOS.

In the above example, 
first row has following sequence (argmax) => 1,2,0,2

Second row has following sequence => 1,1,2,2

Third row has following sequence => 1,1,9,1

So my mask should be

```
[[1,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0],
[1,1,1,1]
```

The mask will ensure, the values post the EOS is ignored or not considered in calculating the loss.

Below is my code snipped I tried

```
    sequence_cluster_asign = keras.backend.argmax(sequence_values,axis=-1)
    loss_mask = []
    for seq in K.tf.unstack(sequence_cluster_asign):
        ##appendEOS- To make sure tf.where is not empty
        seq = tf.concat([seq,endOfSequenceTensor],axis=0)
        endOfSequenceLocation = K.tf.where(K.tf.equal(seq,endOfSequence))[0][0]
        loss_mask.append(tf.sequence_mask(endOfSequenceLocation,max_decoder_seq_length,dtype=tf.float32))
    final_mask = K.stack(loss_mask)
```

**Error encountered : ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?,?)**

Comment: What's your `endOfSequenceTensor` and `max_decoder_seq_length`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get mask in your question, you can use the following method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K

sequence_values = K.placeholder(shape=(None, 4, 3))
sequence_cluster_asign = keras.backend.argmax(sequence_values,axis=-1)

# keras version
result = K.cast(K.less(sequence_cluster_asign,sequence_values.get_shape().as_list()[-1]-1),dtype='int32')
result = K.cumprod(result,axis=-1)

# tensorflow version
# result = tf.cast(tf.less(sequence_cluster_asign,sequence_values.get_shape().as_list()[-1]-1),dtype=tf.int32)
# result = tf.cumprod(result,axis=-1)

predicted = [[[0.1,0.3,0.2],[0.4,0.6,0.8],[0.5,0.2,0.3],[0.0,0.0,0.99]],
             [[0.1,0.3,0.2],[0.4,0.9,0.8],[0.5,0.2,0.9],[0.4,0.6,0.8]],
             [[0.1,0.3,0.2],[0.4,0.9,0.8],[0.5,0.2,0.1],[0.4,0.6,0.1]]]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(result.eval(feed_dict={sequence_values:predicted}))

[[1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```